# How to use CNN to train input data of different size?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning

CNN seems to be implemented mostly for fixed size input. Now I want to use CNN to train some sentences of different size, what are some common methods?

Comment: Always mask the input to the maximum size in your dataset.

Comment: But I am trying to process some articles, the length of which range from 500 to 40,000... Maybe padding is a little inefficient?

Answer (score 8):

The following suggestion is mostly related to CNNs for computer vision taks (in particular for recognition), but might also be helpful in your domain: I would have a look at ["Spatial Pyramid Pooling in Deep Convolutional Networks for Visual Recognition" by He et al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729) proposing a Spatial Pyramid Pooling layer.

The general idea: The convolutional layers of a CNN (and related layers such as pooling, local response normalization etc.) are able to process variable sized input. Therefore, the problem of variable sized input propagates down to the first fully connected/inner product layer which requires a vector of fixed size. He et al. propose to add the Spatial Pyramid Pooling Layer just before the first fully-connected layer (details in the paper). The layer itself works by hierarchically partitioning the feature maps of the last convolutional layer (or the subsequent pooling or response normalization layer) into a fixed number of bins. Within these bins, responses are pooled as usually, creating a fixed-sized output (where the size depends on the hierarchy and number of bins). please see the paper for illustration.

The layer has been implemented based on Caffe and is available on GitHub: [ShaoqingRen/SPP_net](https://github.com/ShaoqingRen/SPP_net).

Comment: This is a good answer about the general concept of variable size input, but it is about computer vision whereas the question was about sentences

Comment: Yes, that's true. That's why I meant is as a suggestion. Naturally, recurrent neural networks would be a good model for working with sentences/words of different length. But the question asks explicitly about CNNs. CNNs are indeed mostly used for fixed size input - independent of the application domain. In computer vision, SPP layers and similar pooling approaches are popular. These ideas are generic and not limited to computer vision, it just happens that I know them from computer vision.

Answer (score 2):

[DynamicCNN - for Theano/Lasagne](https://github.com/FredericGodin/DynamicCNN)  by [Fréderic Godin](http://www.fredericgodin.com/) is an approach which might work better for sentences modeling. It is based on a paper named ["A Convolutional Neural Network for Modelling Sentences"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2188) by [Nal Kalchbrenner](https://www.nal.ai/), Edward Grefenstette, Phil Blunsom from 2014.

Quoting the abstract of the mentioned paper:

> The network uses Dynamic k-Max Pooling, a global pooling operation
>   over linear sequences. The network handles input sentences of varying
>   length and induces a feature graph over the sentence that is capable
>   of explicitly capturing short and long-range relations. The network
>   does not rely on a parse tree and is easily applicable to any
>   language. We test the DCNN in four experiments: small scale binary and
>   multi-class sentiment prediction, six-way question classification and
>   Twitter sentiment prediction by distant supervision. The network
>   achieves excellent performance in the first three tasks and a greater
>   than 25% error reduction in the last task with respect to the
>   strongest baseline.

I hadn't used it myself, but it solved another  similar [sentences modeling problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628014/variable-size-convolutional-neural-network-input-and-fixed-output) on SO.