# Variable size Convolutional Neural Network Input and Fixed output

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to make a CNN model that takes variable size input (sentence matrix) and produce a fixed size output for a subsequent fully connected layer ([similar to this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1058v2.pdf)).

I am trying to implement a dynamic kernel size for a max pooling layer so I need the shape of the input at runtime to achieve this.

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# convolution layer here .... 

tf.nn.max_pool(convolution_output, ksize=[1, s, 1, 1],
                      strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
```

`s` in `ksize=[1, s, 1, 1]` should be inferred from the input shape.

However, I can't find a way to do it with Tensorflow.

Anyone knows a way to do it?

Comment: This sounds similar to what they do here: (https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6071). But unfortunately this is not supported directly by tensorflow yet (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2953). Once added, what you want to do could be just an extension.

Comment: Maybe `tf.reduce_max` could work in this case? Not sure if this will for the paper you are implementing, but at least it works for simple CNN with variable input size.

Comment: tf.reduce_max made the job for what I wanted to do. I wanted to pool depending of the size of the batch size. (Not for every sentences though) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's an old thread, but for people who are looking for a solution. It has been implemented in [tensorflow 1.4.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool)

tf.nn.max_pool() now takes 1d tensor as an input as opposed to a list of ints in the older versions. So you can use a placeholder as the argument of ksize.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way to do it in Tensorflow and had to reimplement my model in theano and use a different solution: [Dynamic KMax Pooling](https://github.com/FredericGodin/DynamicCNN).