# Train a fully convolutional network on different size images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a list named `trainX` containing 2000 of different size images. My network model is fully convolution and has no problem with any of images. The question is that how should I pass the `trainX` to the `fit` method of my model? (don't want to resize or crop the images)(I think I can use `train_on_batch` and pass it one image each time, but I like to use `fit` method if possible)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262860/how-to-use-cnn-to-train-input-data-of-different-size

Comment: @QWERTYL Thanks for comment. No, this does not answer the question. I have no FC layer and my problem is not theoretical (network can pass all images, separately), it's about Keras. If it's still ambiguous, please let me know

Comment: have you tried resizing the images to a common size?

Comment: @QWERTYL As I said in the post, I don't want to do that

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think it is possible to do this without resizing/padding the images because different input dimensions would result in different output dimensions

Comment: It's not that usual. You can find some info from here. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1920